# Calling DLL exports in x64dbg

Tags: ollydbg, debugging, debuggers, x86-64, x64dbg

I am attempting to debug a x64bit dll with x64dbg. Is there an export caller similar to Ollydbg? I checked the documents and haven't seen anything.

Answer (score 1):

I talked to the people over at x64dbg. The export caller feature does not exist in x64dbg.